# Validate input format using javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am having 3 input boxes in my webform and I want to validate all fields using javascript regex while submitting form.

Format for my fields are as follows:

```
NNNN.NN.NNNN (i.e. 1234.56.7890) 

NNN.N (i.e. 123.4) 

NNNNNNN-NNN (i.e. 1234567-890)
```

where N is number or digit only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `\d` matches a digit from 0 to 9.
Using `{4}` matches it 4 times.

You could use [`^\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xf9R5o/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a digit 4 times `\d{4}`
- Match a dot `\.`
- Match a digit 2 times `\d{2}`
- Match a dot `\.`
- Match a digit 4 times `\d{4}`
- The end of the string `$`

For the other two you could use a setup like that.

For NNN.N you could use:

`^\d{3}\.\d$`

For 
NNNNNNN-NNN you could use:

`^\d{7}-\d{3}$`

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\d{3}\.\d{1}|\d{7}-\d{3}`

`\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{n}` Matches exactly `n` times

`|` or

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BULH9J/4)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a jQuery tag, so I recommend [the Masked Inputs plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/)

```js
$('.type1').mask('9999.99.9999');
$('.type2').mask('999.9');
$('.type3').mask('9999999-999');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

<label>NNNN.NN.NNNN <input class=type1></label><br>
<label>NNN.N <input class=type2></lable><br>
<label>NNNNNNN-NNN <input class=type3></label>
```